# trouble including ctime in an objective-c++ project

Tags: c++, xcode, objective-c++, ctime

It keeps failing on this kind of message (just replace tm with clock, difftime, mktime, time, asctime, ctime, gmtime, localtime, strftime :

```
no member named 'tm' in global namespace
```

I'm linking to an external project (Oolong Engine2) built with a makefile in Xcode 4.2
Does anyone recognize what solutions to this problem may be? I googled a bit and saw that others had the same problem, but saw no solutions.

Comment: Have you tried `std::clock` etc?

Comment: Unfortunately, the errors are happening specifically in ctime, so I can't edit the file. It has to be some kind of crazy linking issue I'm not aware of...

Comment: What who? You cannot edit *your own program source code*? That's weird...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was something stupid where headers were being included twice.

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurs if headers are included multiple times.

Check if headers are recursive, if yes, make it non-recursive.